# Deducing Non-Type Template Argument Unsigned Int / size_t

Tags: c++, templates

Im trying to deduce a non-type template argument.

```
#include <iostream>

template <unsigned int S>
void getsize(unsigned int s) { std::cout << s << std::endl; }

int main()
{
  getsize(4U); 
// Id like to do this without explicitly stating getsize<4U>(4);
// or even getsize<4U>(); 
// Is this possible?
}
```

But I am getting error:

```
deduce_szie_t.cpp: In function 'int main()':
deduce_szie_t.cpp:9:15: error: no matching function for call to 'getsize(unsigned int)'
deduce_szie_t.cpp:9:15: note: candidate is:
deduce_szie_t.cpp:4:6: note: template<unsigned int <anonymous> > void getsize(unsigned int)
deduce_szie_t.cpp:4:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
deduce_szie_t.cpp:9:15: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter '<anonymous>'
```

Is it possible to deduce the unsigned int, without having to explicitly state the template parameter?

Id like to have it clean like: getsize(4U)
I want to avoid writing: getsize<4U>()

Thanks alot for any help

Comment: Errr.. deduce it from **what**?

Comment: From the function argument? getsize(4U), deduces unsigned int template parameter

Comment: That makes no sense. You can't deduce static information (the template argument) from a dynamic quantity such as a function argument.

Comment: what exactly do you need the template argument for? Having a template argument always be the value of a parameter seems kind of pointless.

Comment: But if I need that value to be a constant expression wouldnt I need it to be a template argument?

Comment: @bryan: you're basically upset about syntax, correct? You just want to write `getsize(4)` rather than `getsize<4>()`? C++ won't let you, but you could write a macro if it means that much to you ;-)

Comment: Yea, I see what you mean. Probably best that I just get over it.

Comment: Note that there is nothing in the code that says `S` and `s` are related, so there's no reason to deduce anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to deduce a non-type template argument from function arguments, but not in the way you want. It can only be deduced from the type of the function argument, not from the value.

For example:

```
template <unsigned int S>
void getsize(int (*s)[S]) {
    std::cout << "pointer value: " << (void*)s << std::endl;
    std::cout << "deduced size: " << S << std::endl;
}

getsize(static_cast<int (*)[4]>(0));
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code mentions the number `4` a minimal number of times:

```
template <unsigned int N>
void getsize()
{
    std::cout << N << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    getsize<4>();
}
```

You can't possibly mention the number less than one time.

Answer (score 2):

Something wrong with doing this (I *think* this is what you want??)

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Ty>
void getsize(Ty t) { std::cout << t << std::endl; };

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    getsize(4U);
    return 0;
}
```